# After using the jQuery ".css" method, how do you change it back to normal?

Tags: jquery

This is my original CSS for my `#frame` div.

```
....#frame{ 
    position:relative; 
    top:35px; 
}
```

Then, I use jQuery to change the CSS of my div...

```
$('#frame').css("position","absolute");
$('#frame').css("left",50);
```

Now, how do I clear all those changes, and revert back to normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't without explicitly setting it back to the old property values.

I'd probably use a separate class e.g.:

```
.alternativeFrame {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
}
```

And then use addClass and removeClass:-

```
$('#frame').addClass('alternativeFrame');
$('#frame').removeClass('alternativeFrame');
```

Or just:-

```
$('#frame').toggleClass('alternativeFrame');
```

Also remember that you can chain your selectors together for ease and speed, so
for your first example you can end up doing:-

```
$('#frame').css("position","absolute").css("left",50);
```

Comment: You can also pass a dictionary to the `css` function: $('#frame').css({"position": "absolute", "left": 50});